# Next.js Error serializing `.res` returned from `getServerSideProps`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting the error below, when I use getServerSideProps function to retrieve data from Binance API.

```
import binance from "../config/binance-config";

export async function getServerSideProps() {

  const res = await binance.balance((error, balances) => {
    console.info("BTC balance: ", balances.BTC.available);
  });

  return {
    props: {
      res,
    },
  };
}
```

---

```
import Binance from "node-binance-api"

const binance = new Binance().options({
  APIKEY: 'xxx',
  APISECRET: 'xxx'
});

export default binance;
```

Error output:

```
Error: Error serializing `.res` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/dashboard".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this error. I would just like to be able to mine (and display) the response by sending it as props in another component.

Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

Here is how I solved it in NextJs

```
// Get Data from Database
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const { params } = ctx;
  const { slug } = params;

  await dbConnect.connect();
  const member = await Member.findOne({ slug }).lean();
  await dbConnect.disconnect();

  return {
    props: {
      member: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(member)), // <== here is a solution
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Is the dbConnect.disconnect called for performance reasons?

Comment: this is called to close the DB connection after performing the query.

Comment: This answer works well. I upvoted. Btw, why this is happening? In another files, I used response directly from API without using `stringify, parse`. What is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your data into json format when you are fetching it through an Api,

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()
  if (!data) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }`enter code here`
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

You can read more detail on this link, https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Comment: I don't have any urls to fetch unfortunately. Hence my problem

Answer (score 0):

put res from API in Curly Brackets

```
    const { res } = await binance.balance((error, balances) => {
    console.info("BTC balance: ", balances.BTC.available);
  });

return {
    props: {
      res,
    },
  };
```